# Memory leak in react application

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, submit, react-props

After clicking on submit I got this warning

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

This is the code

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault()

```
    let source = axios.CancelToken.source();

    dispatch(login(email, password, source.token))
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Result from dispatch");
            props.history.push("/Dashboard");//this is line which casues a warning.
            window.location.reload();
        })
        .catch(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });

}
```

How to avoid this warning? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the warning by adding this variable mounted inside useEffect.
And I'm checking if a component is unmounted.

```
const mounted = useRef(false); 

useEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true;
    return () => { mounted.current = false; };
}, []);

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let source = axios.CancelToken.source();

    dispatch(login(email, password, source.token))
        .then(() => {
            if (!mounted) {
                console.log("Result from dispatch");

                props.history.push("/Dashboard");
                window.location.reload();
            }

        })
        .catch(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
}
```

Comment: Is this still relevant according to the warning removal from react v18 and the discussion in the thread?

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/22114

Answer (score 0):

When `props.history.push('/Dashboard')` is executed, your component gets unmounted, anything after you are trying to execute on this component (like a state update) would cause a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Enes Toraman. Is there any solution for this warning?

Comment: I am not sure but removing window.location.reload() might work, seems a bit unnecessary since you will be directed to a new page and mount a new component. React might be having a trouble with executing such function when the component owns it gets unmounted. Other than that we should check out if that login action does something like a state update in your component.

Comment: Thanks for the help Enes Toraman. I posted the answer down below.